# Create a matrix from a sub matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of size N *-by-* N and I want to create a matrix (10 N) *-by-* (10 N), where each N *-by-* N block is a copy of the original matrix. I would like to do it without `for` loops.

I have tried with the function `kron`, but it only "enlarges" the original matrix.

How can I make this matrix?

Comment: Adriaan's answer is the way to go. But note that with `kron` it can be done (you may have to reverse the inputs): `A = [10 20; 30 40]; B = kron(ones(10), A);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`repmat()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

```matlab
A = rand(10);  % Original 10 x 10 matrix
B = repmat(A, 10);  % Copied 10 times in each direction
```